# UNIX - Negate (if statement)

Tags: unix, if-statement, logical-operators

I have logs files that I would like to see that have not been compress yet (gzip)
I have this and it works but it checks if the files end in .gz.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILES=(
   "/Sandbox/logs/*"
)


for file in ${LOG_FILES[@]}; do
   if [[ $file =~ \.gz$ ]]; then
      echo $file
   fi
done
```

How do I display the files that do not end in .gz?

I tried

```
![ $file =~ \.gz$ ]
!( $file =~ \.gz$ )
```

but I get a syntax error.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The spaces are important. With spaces, you can choose between:

```
for file in ${LOG_FILES[@]}; do
  if [[ ! $file =~ \.gz$ ]]; then
   echo $file
  fi
done


for file in ${LOG_FILES[@]}; do
  if ! [[ $file =~ \.gz$ ]]; then
   echo $file
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
if [[ "$file" != *.gz ]]; then
      echo "$file is not gz"
fi
```